# Apache pig script delete a folder if exists

Tags: apache-pig, sh

I want to delete the output folder of the previous execution through the `apache pig` script. This command works fine.

```
sh [ -e  /home/LocalPig/test ] && rm -rf /home/LocalPig/test
```

but if I write

```
sh OutpuFile=/home/LocalPig/test
sh [ -e OutputFile] && rm -rf OutputFile
```

I got the error about OutputFile!

```
ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : OutputFile
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Parameter Substituion](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution)

```
%declare OutputFile '/home/LocalPig/test'
sh [ -e '$OutputFile' ] && rm -rf '$OutputFile'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solves the problem. Its simply the below command from .pig script file. You don't have to write any shell command. It can be accomplished from within the pig environment using the built in fs command.

Example, put a statement in your pig script like below, it will also not error out due to non-existence of the folder. It will delete if exists or gracefully exists the statement.

```
fs -rm -f -r -R /user/horton/denver_total;
```

Offcourse you can also do a lot of work outside the pig but its very useful to perform any delete within your script that controls creation of the data. It makes life simpler to trace the lineage of create and destroy of that files.